# Usar variables generadas con browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
'use strict';

var counterpart = require('counterpart');
var Translate   = require('react-translate-component');
```

Lo compilo con Browserify:

```
browserify nuevo.js > locale.js
```

Importo en mi index.html el archivo locale.js, y cuando hago en el primero:

```
console.log(counterpart);
console.log(Translate);
```

Me arroja el error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: counterpart is not defined

A que se debe esto? Como puedo acceder a dichas variables?

Comment: *Importo en mi index.js el archivo locale.js* <-- ¿Qué quieres decir con esto?

Comment: Que en mi archivo HTML tengo `<script src="locale.js"></script>`. Ya lo solucioné con window.exports. Gracias por tomarse la molestia

Comment: En cuanto pueda subo la solución